# Codeigniter error for begginner

Tags: codeigniter

I have a problem for this one I'm just started practicing codeigniter. I just Follow one login tutorial and continue with this displaying users information. But I dont know how to display it in member.php. I have 2controller file and 2model file atm. Got an error for this undefined variable result and  Invalid argument supplied for foreach().

Thankyou much appreciated :)

user_model.php

```
class User_model extends CI_Model{

  public function get_users(){
      $this->db->select('firstname');
      $this->db->select('lastname');
      $this->db->from('login');
      $query = $this->db->get();
      return $result = $query->result();
  }
}
```

user_controller.php

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class User_controller extends CI_Controller {

   public function display_user(){
       $data= array();
       $this->load->model('user_model');    
       $data['result'] = $this->user_model->get_users();
       $this->load->view('member', $data);
   }
}
```

view:  member.php

```
<table>
    <?php foreach($result as $row) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?=$row->firstname;?></td>
        <td><?=$row->lastname;?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Your last line in user_controller.php is wrong. You need to pass array to view. Please replace $result to $data and should be ok. Also you want to make sure that you get some users in that result.I suggest to do if(!empty($result)) before foreach.

Comment: I edited my post @pr0metheus im still getting error sir :(

Comment: Can you paste whole error that you have?

Comment: can you load modal in your controller

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: result

Filename: views/member.php

Line Number: 20

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\ci_attl\application\views\member.php
Line: 20
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\ci_attl\application\controllers\main.php
Line: 17
Function: view

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\ci_attl\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once @pr0metheus

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: views/member.php

Line Number: 20

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\ci_attl\application\views\member.php
Line: 20
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\ci_attl\application\controllers\main.php
Line: 17
Function: view

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\ci_attl\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once   @pr0metheus

Comment: User_controller/member in this line User_controller is folder in your view or not

Comment: User_controller from Controllers folder.   member from Views folder @AslamPatel

Comment: ok so remove User_controller  use like $this->load->view('member', $data);

Comment: still same issue sir @AslamPatel can you help me pls and we move to chat ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134964/discussion-between-aslam-patel-and-genina-anne-gabuten).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you try to access wrong url with wrong method, that's why error was show up.

Your code was fine, after fix loading view with $data array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your Model may be it help you

```
public function get_users(){
  $this->db->select('firstname,lastname');
  $this->db->from('login');
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $result = $query->result();}
```